# hover more than one element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to use more than one element in jQuery hover? 
This code is only for `a` elements but how may you use it for `div`,`texterea`,`a` and `li` elements together?

Example:

```
$("a").hover(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("class");
    $("#helparea").text(id);
}, 
function () {
    $("#helparea").empty();
});
```

Comment: You might be looking for the multiple selector (http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$("a")` selects all `a` elements.

If you want to select more, use `$("div,textarea,a,li")`.

Read [jQuery's documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) [on the matter](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

Answer (score 1):

Use `$('div, textarea, a, li').hover(...)`. JQuery will accept any valid CSS selector so just seperate your selectors with commas.

Comment: ... or a variant that's (a) valid, and (b) what the OP asked for.

Comment: That was syntactically valid … so long as the three variables are defined and `a` contains something jQuery accepts. ;)

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal - yeah noticed the lack of delimiters around the selector and edited the answer. Cheers.